# Electric field at a point infinitely close to an arbitrary surface charge

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge

My question is of two parts:

**(i)** I know electric field due to an infinite plane sheet of charge at a point (finite distance $d$ away) is $2 \pi\ k\ \sigma$. From this, by reducing the linear dimensions of our system, **can we conclude that electric field due to a finite plane sheet of charge at a point infinitely close to it will remain $2 \pi\ k\ \sigma$ ?** (because $2, \pi, k, \sigma$ are all independent of the size of our system).

**(ii)** **Is there a way to show that electric field due to any surface charge at a point infinitely close to it will still be $2 \pi\ k\ \sigma$ ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can we conclude that electric field due to a finite plane sheet of charge at a point infinitely close to it will remain 2π k σ

Yes. The distance plays no role in this scenario.

> Is there a way to show that electric field due to any surface charge at a point infinitely close to it will still be 2π k σ?

Heuristically, if you take an arbitrary surface and zoom in infinitely close then to first order it is a plane. Similar to how you can decompose any curve into a polynomial using Taylor series expansion you can do the same thing with a surface. The “first order” term is a plane and so the field due to the first order term is the above field. As you move away from the surface second and higher order terms become important.

Comment: So do you mean electric field at a point infinitely close to any arbitrary shaped surface charge of varying charge density is always $2 \pi k \sigma$?

Comment: Why is there no contribution due to the rest of the points on our surface charge which are at a finite distance from the field point.

Comment: There is a contribution from other points, but it is a second or higher order contribution. It exists but until you go some finite distance away it is small compared to the influence of the nearby surface.